# Function for Import catalog products

Tags: magento2, import, importexport

Which function will be called in CatalogImportExport module on click of 'Import' button when U import bulk csv products in System->Import->Products

Comment: i want to override this module in order to add additional functionality apart from saving the productdata

Answer (score 3):

Basically the `importSource` from `Magento/ImportExport/Model/Import` is called.

Then the `processImport` from that same class is called.

At this point it's still pretty abstract.

But from the following line:

```
   $this->_getEntityAdapter()->importData();
```

The system starts importing based on the entity type (in your case products)

The `importData` method is defined in `Magento/ImportExport/Model/Import/AbstractEntity` but all it does is calling `_importData`

Now we go to `Magento/CatalogImportExport/Model/Import/Product` and here's what happens based on the behavior chosen:

1. Product deletions in `_deleteProducts` method
2. Product replacement in `_replaceProducts`
3. Product creation in `_saveProductsData`

Comment: Raphael, i want to add only the product_ids of those products which i updated into my custom table..can you please say how i have to override this? When i edit individual product then productids are getting saved, but not by import

Comment: Any suggestion for this?

Comment: @SachinS well that's a different question than what you asked I'm not sure about that

Comment: Ok in my case, when i have to saveProducts data, is it enuf if i override Magento/CatalogImportExport/Model/Import/Product ?

Comment: @SachinS I guess so yes