# Magento 2 Import Performance

Tags: magento-2.1, import, performance

For Magento 1 there is an informative report about the import performance in  https://www.integer-net.de/produktimport-mit-magento/

For Magento 2 and a shop project with < 10 k simple products we successfully used

```
/*
* @var \Magento\ImportExport\Model\Import $import
*/
$import->validateSource($csvSource);
$import->importSource()
```

see 
[Function for Import catalog products](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128072/function-for-import-catalog-products/128076#128076).

But for 300 k products we see a really poor performance for this approach.

Are there any tweaks that allow us to reach the 100 products/seconds or more that the ImportExport of Magento 1 delivered?